# Phalcon cassandra pdo error and I dont want to hide notice. I want to fix it

Tags: php, cassandra, phalcon

I am using cassandra pdo with phalcon it's working fine but its returnig rowcount notice when i am trying to insert data using create method.

> *Notice: Undefined index: rowcount *

Can anyone suggest me how to fix it ??

```
$instance = new $model();
$instance->save($obj_data); //this lines returns notice.
```

As on now I am using YAcassandra pdo with phalcon. 
URL (https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO/)

Does anyone know any other PDO which is easy to use with phalcon and supports all datatypes ??

Thanks

Comment: I dont want to hide the notice I want to fix it. @john its not a duplicate question

Comment: how one can even figure out the problem when you given link of library not code you hare written

Comment: I am using $instance->save($obj_data);

Comment: well i believe John Conde isnt stupid guy he has answered  2435 question and got 6k upvote  ... and you can still edit question and if  community found it good  we will reopen it thanks

Comment: I apologize for it. yes he has good reputation. I am trying to fix it from last 2 days and he marked as duplicate within a second so just frustration .